# Delphi wmi отслеживание запуска и закрытие программ

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, wmi

Пишу приложение для отслеживание запуска программ.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;

function KeyPressed:boolean;
var
lpNumberOfEvents     : DWORD;
lpBuffer             : _INPUT_RECORD;
lpNumberOfEventsRead : DWORD;
nStdHandle           : THandle;
begin
  Result:=false;
  nStdHandle := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
  lpNumberOfEvents:=0;
  GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(nStdHandle,lpNumberOfEvents);
  if lpNumberOfEvents<> 0 then
  begin
    PeekConsoleInput(nStdHandle,lpBuffer,1,lpNumberOfEventsRead);
    if lpNumberOfEventsRead <> 0 then
    begin
      if lpBuffer.EventType = KEY_EVENT then
      begin
        if lpBuffer.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown then
          Result:=true
        else
          FlushConsoleInputBuffer(nStdHandle);
      end
      else
      FlushConsoleInputBuffer(nStdHandle);
    end;
  end;
end;

Procedure  Monitor_Async_Win32_Process;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
  wbemErrTimedout     = $80043001;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FEventResult  : OLEVariant;
begin
  //Create the WMI Scripting Instance
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  //Connect to the WMI service
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  //Execute the event in sync way
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery('Select * from __InstanceCreationEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance ISA "Win32_Process"');
  while not KeyPressed do
  begin
    try
     //receive the event , wai until 100 milliseconds.
     FEventResult := FWbemObjectSet.NextEvent(100);
    except
     on E:EOleException do
     //Check for the timeout and ignore
     if EOleException(E).ErrorCode=HRESULT(wbemErrTimedout) then
       FEventResult:=Null
     else
     raise;
    end;

    //process the received event info
    if not VarIsNull(FEventResult) then
    begin
      Writeln(Format('Caption   %s',[FEventResult.TargetInstance.Caption]));
      Writeln(Format('ProcessId %s',[FEventResult.TargetInstance.ProcessId]));
      Writeln('');
    end;

    //clear the olevariant variable
    FEventResult:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;

var
  Success  : HResult;
begin
 try
    Writeln('Press any key to exit');
    Success:=CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      Monitor_Async_Win32_Process;
    finally
      case Success of
        S_OK, S_FALSE: CoUninitialize;
      end;
    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Readln;
end.
```

В этом месте выбивает ошибку. "Timed out"

```
     //receive the event , wai until 100 milliseconds.
     FEventResult := FWbemObjectSet.NextEvent(100);
```

Использую статью 
https://theroadtodelphi.com/2011/04/18/delphi-and-wmi-events/

Comment: Delphi + статья 2011 года...

Comment: Пробовал хук WH_SHELL. Но он не отлавливает многое.
Использую Delphi 7.
Ну а чем тогда пользоваться? Каким методом это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кроме использования кода из статьи было бы неплохо еще и понимать что этот код делает.

Судя по коду в секции `except` и комментарию `Check for the timeout and ignore`, исключение по таймауту - это нормальное поведение. В обработчике исключения ожидаемый результат (`FEventResult`) обнуляется. Далее идет проверка результата вызова `FWbemObjectSet.NextEvent(100)` (`if not VarIsNull(FEventResult) then`) и если он не нулевой, в консоль выводятся название и ID нового процесса.

Насколько я понял, этот код в цикле ожидает в течение 100 мс появления нового процесса. Если за 100 мс новый процесс не появился, то, возникающее исключение перехватывается, и процесс ожидания повторяется. Если новый процесс возник, то в консоль выводятся его название и ID.

Чтобы отладчик не прерывал выполнение кода при возникновении исключения, добавьте это исключение в список игнорирования в отладчике. Или запустите код без отладчика.

Comment: Помогли) А как можно теперь заголовок окна получить? Ну допустим вкладки хрома.

Comment: Тут уже я вам не помогу. Смотрите что еще можно вытащить из этого `FEventResult`, какой он интерфейс реализует. Что еще можно вытащить запросами из интерфейса `WbemScripting.SWbemLocator` https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa393720(v=vs.85).aspx Посмотрите что еще можно добыть имея ID процесса https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683215(v=vs.85).aspx